# Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:8051

Tags: node.js, docker, hyperledger-fabric

I am running a modified version of the `byfn` tutorial, with 5 orderers, 1 org, 2 peers and 1 ca service with docker-compose. Locally I am running a node application, using `node v10.18.1` on `macOs Catalina`.
The `hyperledger fabric version 1.4` is also being used.

I have tried replacing the path in the `connection.json` file relating to the grpcUrl's from `localhost` to the IP for the containers provided with `docker inspect` command and also to `0.0.0.0` without any success, have also used telnet to grep the exposed ports and have run `docker ps` to check that all containers are running with the correct ports.

In my code I can successfully register the admin and other users, but it fails when I try to connect to the gateway to invoke the chaincode.

I am constantly getting the error in my API logs:

```
2020-01-15T15:42:37.920Z - error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:7051
2020-01-15T15:42:37.922Z - error: [Channel.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:7051
2020-01-15T15:42:40.929Z - error: [Remote.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:8051
2020-01-15T15:42:40.929Z - error: [Channel.js]: Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:8051
2020-01-15T15:42:40.930Z - error: [Network]: _initializeInternalChannel: Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 2 Peers. Last error was Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:8051
level:warn time:2020-01-15T15:42:40.932Z message: "x-request-id_ac5294fd-9587-4432-87d9-ada4e73a1142 creating user product Unable to initialize channel. Attempted to contact 2 Peers. Last error was Error: Failed to connect before the deadline URL:grpcs://localhost:8051"
```

Why am I getting this error?

My `connection.json` file is:

```
{
    "name": "first-network-org1",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1": {
            "mspid": "Org1MSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.org1.example.com",
                "peer1.org1.example.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.org1.example.com"
            ]
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:7051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----...\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer0.org1.example.com",
                "hostnameOverride": "peer0.org1.example.com"
            }
        },
        "peer1.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpcs://localhost:8051",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----...\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            },
            "grpcOptions": {
                "ssl-target-name-override": "peer1.org1.example.com",
                "hostnameOverride": "peer1.org1.example.com"
            }
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "https://localhost:7054",
            "caName": "ca-org1",
            "tlsCACerts": {
                "pem": "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----...\n-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n"
            },
            "httpOptions": {
                "verify": false
            }
        }
    }
}
```

These are the dependencies in my package.json file (bare in mind I have tried manually installing the latest grpc module without any success):

```
"dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "fabric-ca-client": "^1.4.4",
    "fabric-client": "^1.4.4",
    "fabric-network": "^1.4.4",
    "helmet": "^3.15.1",
    "http-status": "^1.3.1",
    "joi": "^14.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.11",
    "nconf": "^0.10.0",
    "request-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "swagger-stats": "^0.95.7",
    "uuid": "^3.3.2",
    "winston": "^3.2.1",
    "xss": "^1.0.3"
  }
```

Here is my failing code:

```
const initGateway = async (params) => {
  try {
    const {
      wallet,
      identity,
      discovery, // object with { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true }
      channelName,
      contractName
    } = params;

    // Create a new gateway for connecting to our peer node.
    const gateway = new Gateway();
    await gateway.connect(ccpPath, { wallet, identity, discovery });

    // Get the network (channel) our contract is deployed to.
    const network = await gateway.getNetwork(channelName);
    logger.info({ message: `NETWORK ${network}` });
    // Get the contract from the network.
    const contract = network.getContract(contractName);

    return { gateway, contract };
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
};

const createProduct = async (dataObj) => {
  try {
    const {
      userIdentity,
      seller,
      value,
      description,
      issueDateTime,
      productId
    } = dataObj;
    // Create a new file system based wallet for managing identities
    const wallet = new FileSystemWallet(walletFilePath);

    const params = {
      wallet,
      identity: userIdentity,
      discovery: { enabled: true, asLocalhost: true },
      channelName: 'mychannel',
      contractName: 'mychaincode'
    };
    // Get the contract from the network.
    const { gateway, contract } = await initGateway(params);

    await contract.submitTransaction('setForSale', seller, productId, issueDateTime, value, description);

    // Disconnect from the gateway.
    await gateway.disconnect();
  } catch (err) {
    throw err;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Make sure you enabled TLS communications for peers by looking up to `CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true` flag in your docker-compose file. If it is not set to true, then modify peer urls in connection profiles from `grpcs://localhost:7051` to `grpc://localhost:7051`

Comment: Tried both already and `CORE_PEER_TLS_ENABLED=true` was already set

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question here.

I had noticed that the `grpcOptions` in the connection file had wrong values. Namely the `ssl-target-name-override` and `hostnameOverride` were pointing to non-existent docker container names. Setting them to the correct peer container names fixed this error. #facepalm